# How to Android OTP Firebase Reauthenticate?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am having a problem when combining the two provide logins on firebase, the problem here is that firebase must reauthenticate before combining the two login providers, how do I OTP to reauthenticate?

```
private void linkWithEmail(String email, String password) {
    // i want linking OTP with email at firebase
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
    firebaseUser.linkWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            //do email verification
            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                if(task1.isSuccessful()){ 
                    //email verification has been sended
                    //my own code.....
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Verification Failed: " + task1.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }else{
            //exception firebase reauthentication will be here
            Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Linking Failed: "+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```